# How to use few joins with one right join in table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have one select with few joins and i want to show all rows from one table(RIGHT JOIN).
here is my query

```
MERGE #Players AS Target
                USING (SELECT DT.[TimeId] AS [Selector],                            
                                [CurrencyId], 
                                PT.Name                                 [ProductType],
                                COUNT(*) FirstTimeDepositors,
                                PT.Id FirstDepositProductTypeId
                      FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DP
                       JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimTimeZone] DT ON DP.[FirstDepositTimeId] = DT.TimeUTCId 
                      RIGHT JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductType] PT ON PT.Id = DP.FirstDepositProductTypeId                     
                      AND [FirstDepositTimeId] BETWEEN @DimStartDateUTC AND @DimEndDateUTC
                      AND DP.[IsInternalAccount] = 0  
                      GROUP BY DT.[TimeId],[CurrencyId],PT.Name,PT.Id) AS Source
                ON (Target.[Time] = Source.[Selector] AND Target.[CurrencyId] = Source.[CurrencyId] AND Target.[ProductType] = Source.[ProductType] )
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                      UPDATE SET Target.[FirstTimeDepositorsCounts] = Source.[FirstTimeDepositors]
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
                      INSERT ([Time],[CurrencyId],[ProductType],[FirstTimeDepositorsCounts],[FirstDepositProductTypeId])
                      VALUES (Source.[Selector],Source.[CurrencyId],[ProductType],Source.[FirstTimeDepositors],Source.[FirstDepositProductTypeId]);
```

But this doesn't work fine for me , plus i want to have WHERE clause if it's possible with right join

Comment: Who uses `RIGHT JOIN` these days ?

Comment: I don't know who uses :) I need a solution that will join all tables and take all ProductTypes from DimProductType table. If you know some better solution you are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the joined table you can add it to the join clause or use a subquery.

```
 RIGHT JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductType] PT 
    ON PT.Id = DP.FirstDepositProductTypeId And PT.Field = "What you want"
```

or

```
RIGHT JOIN 
    (Select Fields From [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductType] Where Field = "What you want") PT 
    ON PT.Id = DP.FirstDepositProductTypeId
```

Comment: Oh yeah I knew that, doh :)